# how to access fields of derived class from another derived class in multilevel inheritance

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, super

I am trying to understand multilevel inheritance through this program

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Student{
    public
    int rno;
    String stud_name;
    Student(int r, String name){
        rno = r;
        stud_name = name;
    }
    
} 
class sports extends Student{
    public
    int pts;
    sports(int rno, String name, int points){//line 16
        pts = points;
        super(rno,name); //line 18
    }
    
}
class results extends sports{
    public
    int [] mark = new int[2];
    int sum =0;
    results(int rno, String name, int marks[], int points){
        super(rno,name,points);
        this.mark = marks;
        
    }
    
    void display(){
        for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
            sum += mark[i];
        }
            
        System.out.println("Student Name: "+super.stud_name);
        System.out.println("Student Roll no"+super.rno);
        System.out.println("Sports points: "+super.pts);
        System.out.println("Total marks: "+sum);
        
        
    }
}


class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
     
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int rollno;
        int points;
        String name;
        int[] marks = new int[5];
        
        System.out.println("Enter Student name");
        name = s.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("Enter Student roll no");
        rollno = s.nextInt();
        
        for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
        System.out.println("Enter the"+i+"th mark");
        marks[i] = s.nextInt();
        }
        
        
        System.out.println("Enter Sports pts");
        points = s.nextInt();
        
        results stud = new results(rollno, name, marks, points);
        stud.display();
        
        
        
    }
}
```

but I am getting these errors

> Main.java:16: error: constructor Student in class Student cannot be applied to given types;
> sports(int rno, String name, int points){
> ^
> required: int,String
> found: no arguments
> reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
> Main.java:18: error: call to super must be first statement in constructor
> super(rno,name);
> ^
> 2 errors

When I tried to solve this error I got a new Doubt

1)If **super** keyword refers to immediate parent class right, then how am I able to access variables `rno` and `stud_name` from *results class*(*results class's* immediate parent is *sports class* right not *student class*). If I understood it wrongly and *results class's* immediate parent is *student class* then how do I access the variables in *sports class* from *results class*.

And please help me solve this error, I have tried searching for solutions and examples online but I only find programs with 1 child class.

Comment: Just swap the order of the lines so `super` is called first.

Comment: First of all, you need to move super() to the first line right after the definition of a constructor.

Comment: I'm also not seeing `public` used correctly.  Where are the package definitions?  It's possible that a constructor is not visible because it is not declared public (none of them are).

Comment: I did it and it solved the error can you guys say what caused the error?

Comment: The main thing is that `super` used to call a ctor *MUST* be the first line in a constructor.  That's required by the language.  I'm guessing the other error was caused by the fact that the first error cased the constructor to be "bad" and therefore not usable when you tried to call it.

Comment: oh okay thank you.

Comment: `System.out.println("Student Name: "+super.stud_name);` should just use `this.stud_name`.  The fields are accessible because they’re inherited.  The same applies to the following two lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error itself is easy to solve, just put the super() call at the beginning of the constructor, like the error message told so:

```
    sports(int rno, String name, int points){
        super(rno,name);
        pts = points;
    }
```

However, there are many things that's smelly in your code, I'd suggest you to look into them:

- Clean code: follow the naming conventions, start class names with capital letter like Sport or Result, and don't let them be plurar
- Understanding the concepts of OOP, inheritance is not for expanding a class with more fields. Inheritance is for extending a class' functionality, so the child can be used wherever the parent could.
  If you want to have new fields in your class, just put a new class in it's fields, like this:

```
class results {  // no need for inheritance
    ...
    Sports sports;

    results(int rno, String name, int marks[], int points) {
        sports = new Sports(rno, name, points);  // initialize the field
        this.mark = marks;

    }

    void display() {
        ...
        System.out.println("Student Name: " + sports.stud_name);  // you reach it's fields like this
    }
}
```

- You should also put different class definitions in different .java files, and look into the use of visibility modifiers